# Javascript regex - if do not match a part of url continue

Tags: javascript, regex

i need a regex from CNN url to match the url part for their embeded video.
it should find part of URL between videos/ & /video.

it's easy with this simple regex

```
videos\/(.*)\/video
```

//www.cnn.com/videos/`business/2019/12/17/dawn-powerwash-dish-spray-zw-orig.cnn-business`/video/playlists/stories-worth-watching/

But some url do not have the second '`/video`' word.

//www.cnn.com/videos/`business/2019/11/15/modern-glass-house-new-york-green-roof-orig.cnn-business`

I need that part after the word `video` til the end

In my example here, the third one do not work because there's no the second `/video/` part in the url.

EX: [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/UlOCL7/2/)

Comment: Use an alternation to assert the end of the string https://regex101.com/r/zHr1w2/1

Comment: `/videos\/(.*?)(?:\/video|$)/`